# Nested MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, nested

I have this MySQL statement which works fine:

```
SELECT claim_items.item_id, claim_items.quantity*items_rate.rate as per_item
FROM claim_items, items_rate 
WHERE claim_items.claim_id = 1 AND claim_items.item_id = items_rate.items_id
```

However what I want to do is to get the sum of the per_item field generated in the MySQL statement. Is it possible to do a nested statement to do that? I know I could create a view and then do it, but would prefer to do it in one statement.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the sum over all rows you can do it like that (using explicit joins for better readability):

```
SELECT SUM( claim_items.quantity * items_rate.rate )
FROM claim_items
JOIN items_rate ON ( items_rate.items_id = claim_items.item_id )
WHERE claim_items.claim_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks that does indeed looks nicer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.id, SUM(t.per_item)
from 
(
SELECT claim_items.item_id as id, claim_items.quantity*items_rate.rate as per_item
FROM claim_items, items_rate 
WHERE claim_items.claim_id = 1 AND claim_items.item_id = items_rate.items_id
) t
group by t.id
```

Hope this should help.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I removed the ID though because otherwise it wont calculate the sum :)